# Not able to spawn threads in Jenkins groovy pipeline

Tags: multithreading, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I want to run multiple threads in my groovy pipeline. Here is my pipeline

```
node{
    List<Thread> cleanupThreads = new ArrayList<>(100);
    """1 2 3 4 5 6""".split().each{
        def th = new Thread({
            Random rand = new Random()
            def wait = (long)(rand.nextDouble() * 1000)
            this.sleep wait
            println "Running Thread ${this.getName()}"
        })

        cleanupThreads.add(th)
    }
    cleanupThreads.each {it.start() }
    cleanupThreads.each {it.join() }
}
```

When i run it, i don't see any "Running Thread ${this.getName()}" output line in console

```
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test_jobs/multithreaded_groovy_pipeline
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Any idea what wrong here? Does Jenkins pipeline support multi-threading?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you want to code groovy multithread functionality into pipeline script which is not advisable. If you want to run different jobs in parallel you can use [Parallel](https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2017/09/25/declarative-1/) stage functionality. Please find below sample

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage ("Test Stage"){
           steps {
               parallel(
                   job1: {
                       echo "Inside 1st Job"
                   },
                   job2: {
                       echo "Inside 2nd Job"
                   },
                   job3: {
                       echo "Inside 3rd Job"
                   }
                   )
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: I am actually interested in doing multi threading in Jenkins pipeline. "parallel" is also fine but just curious about doing it in groovy way.